# A function that brings back the prime number just before it?

Tags: number-theory, notation, prime-numbers

Is there a function that brings the prime number just before it?

I.e P(18)=17 P(6)=5 P(28)=23;

I know how weird that sounds.

Comment: If you mean an arithmetical function, you can make it as you want. nth prime will be an example.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: In WA, you can use nextprime to find the next prime, or use it with a negative offset to find the previous one. [*Example 1*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=previous+prime+10), [*Example 2*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=next+prime+100000000). You can review the MMA documentation to see which algorithms they use. Of course, it will have limits.

Comment: @MohamedAyman I misunderstood your question. Sorry.

Comment: Given that you can define it, there is such a function - it is clearly well-defined with a domain and a range.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a function. You have defined it. P(x) = the smallest prime less than x. This is fully defined for all x>2. What I think you want is an algorithm to determine it efficiently. That depends on other things. If you only want to do this once, simply check x-1, x-2, x-3 etc and stop when you find a prime (lots of algorithms for checking primality). If you are doing this a lot, with smallish values of x, it might be better to run a sieve of Eratosthenes to find all the primes less than x first, and then check x-1, x-2 etc against this table.

Comment: So I can call a function P(X) that finds the prime just before it, right? But how can I find such an algorithm?

Comment: @Peter there is no known polynomial-time algorithm for the nextprime function, I suppose the same is likely true for prevprime.  I interpreted it as a notation question and I edited the tags accordingly, I apologize to OP if that was not the intent.

Comment: @DanBrumleve based on Mohamed's comment I think he is after an algorithm, so I posted the basics as an answer. Though I did like your answer. This would be a lot easier (and he would get better answers) if he provided some context for his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard notations are $p_n$ for the $n^{th}$ prime and $\pi(n)$ for the number of primes less than or equal to $n$.  Combining these we have $p_{\pi(n-1)}$ as an expression for the largest prime less than $n$.

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming this is **not** a notational question)

If you want an algorithm to find the largest prime less than n, then it is simple. Consider n-1. Check to see if it has any divisors other than 1 and itself. If it doesn't, this is the largest prime. If it does have divisors other than 1 and itself, consider n-2 in the same manner, then n-3. Continue until you reach a prime.

If you want an efficient algorithm, that rather depends on what you care about. As I said in the comments, if you want to do this many times but your numbers are less than (say) 100 million, then you should build a sieve of Eratosthenes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes to precalculate which are prime. Then you just step down until you reach a prime.

If this is a one-off calculation then calculating every prime in advance is inefficient and if the numbers are large will consume a lot of memory. So you need to have some method eg isPrime(n) which returns true if the number is prime. Then you just call this for n-1, n-2, etc until you get a prime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538644/c-determine-if-a-number-is-prime explores this in some detail.

Comment: If Cramér's conjecture is true then this algorithm (counting down until we find a prime) will run in polynomial time.  So it's not even really known to be inefficient, it's just not known to be efficient. :)